# onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, spotify

I'm making a clone of Spotify using **NextJS and React**. I want to use **Web Playback SDK** to play tracks, but when I import the script of SDK, it always `not defined`. Please help me to solve this problem, I have searched too much and not figure out what was the reason. Here is my code and error screen:

```
type Props = {
  children?: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
};

export default function Main({ children }: Props) {
  const recentlyTracks = useRecentlyTracks();
  const newRelease = useNewRelease();
  const futuredPlaylists = useFuturedPlaylists();

  return (
    <HomeContext.Provider
      value={{ recentlyTracks, newRelease, futuredPlaylists }}
    >
      <Script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js" />
      <div className="w-main h-full bg-gradient-to-t from-start to-end overflow-y-scroll no-scrollbar pb-4">
        <Header />
        {children}
      </div>
    </HomeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the  tag directly within the JSX, which is not the way to properly load the SDK in a react application. Take a look here:

https://github.com/niekert/use-spotify-web-playback-sdk for a solution on how to potentially load the SDK correctly using a hooks based approach.

Comment: Can you explain what I was wrong in my way? I'm learning and I want to understand in deep?

Comment: Well, essentially when the script tag gets rendered in the HTML, it's already too late for your code to find it, it's to do with the order of execution specifically when using react.